# ROW_NUMBER() column is invalid and trying to speed up query help

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use the ROW_NUMBER function, but I am running into two problems. 1) Because I am ordering the count in descending order, the rowid does not start at 1, it starts at 41 for example. 2) When I try to bring back rowid between 42 and 52, it says rowid is an invalid column.  Here is the toned down query with some extra columns taken out so it is more readable:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1) AS rowid,
hrl.column0
(SELECT top 1 bus from hc WHERE column2 = hc.column2) AS c,
'Site' as Based,
column1, column2, column3, column4,
CASE WHEN status = '1' Then 'Active'
     WHEN status = '2' Then 'Canceled'
ELSE
   'Unknown'
END as column5,
column6,
(select count(*) from hrl where column1 = hrl.column1) as [cnt]
FROM hrl
INNER JOIN hc on hc.column2 = hrl.column2
INNER JOIN rsc on rsc.column3 = hrl.column3
LEFT OUTER JOIN  gmt on gmt.[column7] = hrl.[column7]
where bus LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY [cnt] desc,rowid
and  rowid >= 1 AND rowid <= 10 -- Says rowid is invalid
```

Here is the data I want

```
RowID Business Count

1     Green    50
2     Red      30
3     Blue     20
```

Here is what I am getting:

```
RowID Business Count

3     Blue     20
2     Red      30
1     Green    50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it into the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1) AS rowid,
    hrl.column0,
    (SELECT top 1 bus from hc WHERE column2 = hc.column2) AS c,
    'Site' as Based,
    column1, column2, column3, column4,
    CASE WHEN status = '1' Then 'Active'
         WHEN status = '2' Then 'Canceled'
    ELSE
       'Unknown'
    END as column5,
    column6,
    (select count(*) from hrl where column1 = hrl.column1) as [cnt]
    FROM hrl
    INNER JOIN hc on hc.column2 = hrl.column2
    INNER JOIN rsc on rsc.column3 = hrl.column3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  gmt on gmt.[column7] = hrl.[column7]
    where bus LIKE '%test%'
) sq
WHERE rowid >= 1 AND rowid <= 10
ORDER BY [cnt] DESC
```

If you just want `TOP 10 column1` rows ordered then by `[cnt]`, you may use:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10
           hrl.column0,
           (SELECT top 1 bus from hc WHERE column2 = hc.column2) AS c,
           'Site' as Based,
           column1, column2, column3, column4,
           CASE WHEN status = '1' Then 'Active'
                WHEN status = '2' Then 'Canceled'
                ELSE 'Unknown'
           END as column5,
           column6,
           (select count(*) from hrl where column1 = hrl.column1) as [cnt]
    FROM   hrl
    INNER JOIN hc on hc.column2 = hrl.column2
    INNER JOIN rsc on rsc.column3 = hrl.column3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  gmt on gmt.[column7] = hrl.[column7]
    WHERE  bus LIKE '%test%'
    ORDER BY column1
) sq
ORDER BY [cnt] DESC
```

Or, if you just need `ORDER BY [cnt] DESC`, try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10
       hrl.column0,
       (SELECT top 1 bus from hc WHERE column2 = hc.column2) AS c,
       'Site' as Based,
       column1, column2, column3, column4,
       CASE WHEN status = '1' Then 'Active'
            WHEN status = '2' Then 'Canceled'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
       END as column5,
       column6,
       (select count(*) from hrl where column1 = hrl.column1) as [cnt]
FROM   hrl
INNER JOIN hc on hc.column2 = hrl.column2
INNER JOIN rsc on rsc.column3 = hrl.column3
LEFT OUTER JOIN  gmt on gmt.[column7] = hrl.[column7]
WHERE  bus LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY [cnt] DESC
```

Comment: Actually, stupid me was missing the FROM in the outer select.  What you told me works, but it is not bringing back the cnt in descinding order which is what I want.

Comment: Post some sample data and a recordset you'd want to get.

Comment: My query (and your initial query) should return exactly this. Are you sure you didn't miss ORDER BY [cnt] DESC in the end? And by sample data I meant unfiltered data, i. e. content of your tables (after all filters but before ROW_NUMBER) AND ORDER BY)

Comment: The query is the same, but what is happening is that the highest count may have rowid of 32 so when the results come back, it starts at record 32, not 1.

Comment: You have ORDER BY COLUMN1 in your ROW_NUMBER() function. Did you put it there intentionally?

Comment: yes, i tried putting order by cnt, but that doesn't work there

Comment: See another update. You'd really better put the sample data from your tables here (not what you are getting now, but what you have in the tables), so that we can see what you want to order by and what you want to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap unsorted data as a CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
;with NotSorted as (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1) AS rowid, 
        hrl.column0, 
        (SELECT top 1 bus from hc WHERE column2 = hc.column2) AS c,
        'Site' as Based, column1, column2, column3, column4,
        CASE WHEN status = '1' Then 'Active'
             WHEN status = '2' Then 'Canceled'
             ELSE 'Unknown'
        END as column5, column6,
        (select count(*) from hrl where column1 = hrl.column1) as [cnt]
    FROM    hrl
            INNER JOIN hc on hc.column2 = hrl.column2
            INNER JOIN rsc on rsc.column3 = hrl.column3
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  gmt on gmt.[column7] = hrl.[column7]
    where   bus LIKE '%test%'
)
select  *
from    NotSorted
ORDER BY [cnt] desc, rowid and  rowid >= 1 AND rowid <= 10
```

As for,

> and  rowid >= 1 AND rowid <= 10 -- Says rowid is invalid

You can't access computed alias directly and you would usually put computed column into a subquery or as a CTE